Facebook doesn't recognize "og:x" tags
In my PHP Codeigniter app focused on movie streaming, I want to add Facebook sharing feature.
I have these the most important og: tags (according to Facebook) enclosed in head tag:

og:image
og:title
og:description

However, if I want to share this website, Facebook doesn't recognize any tags. Output from Facebook debugger looks like this: 
What could be the problem? I don't even know, what to try to fix this issue. You can take look at my website here.

When I visit the link you've provided I am redirected to a login screen. Presumably, Facebook is, too.

Yes, that was exactly the problem. Facebook wasn't able to reach this URL. Thank you!

The problem is, that your site is hidden behind login and we, nor Facebook can access it without logging in.
When I access the URL you provided, I am redirected to login page, because "Watching series and movies is only for registered users". Facebook is therefore redirected too. And even though your movie page has OG tags, your login and signup pages don't.
Facebook can't access the page with OG tags.
You can allow access to movie pages to anonymous users, but disallow them from playing the movie unless they login.

I see, that during the time, I was writing my answer, Chris already provided solution in the comment. Sorry, I didn't notice.
